# how can I make unconditional assert

Tags: c#, assert

I need to have unconditional assert in C#.
This is for the case when my code execution gets to the point in the code where it shouldn`t arrive. I want to assert about that.
All methods od `Assert` are conditional. Of course I can  do `Assert.IsFalse(true)`
But I am not sure it is an elegant way
Any advises are welcome

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to throw an exception?

Comment: what about Assert.Fail()? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.fail.aspx

Comment: Why the downvotes and the vote to close? Maybe it's not extremely well expressed, but this is definitely a question about programming...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco i absolutly aggree with you. Maybe he is designing a UnitTest and just hasn't mentioned...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Therefor you can use

```
Assert.Fail("Some message");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Assert.Fail() which can take a failure message

```
Assert.Fail();
Assert.Fail("Should not get here.");
```